# which is the fastest: 3 Arraylist synchronized or a HashMap with custom structure as value

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, hashtable

i've got to develop a java code which associates data and votes to people.

I've got a class called "Candidate" which contain basic informations about the candidates (and a unique id).

i must then associate successive votes (integers), a reference to a JLabel where to display those votes for this candidate, ...

Which is the best way to do this?

- 3 ArraList (1 for candidates, 1 for votes and 1 for JLabel) of the same length with each index value refering to the data about 1 candidate?
- An HashTable with the candidate as key (hashCoded with uid) and a custom structure as value containing the vote, JLabel reference, and other data...

i know both ArrayList and HashTable are supposed to be O(1) for accessing and O(1) for adding a value at the end, but would they really be as performant?

thanks!

Comment: use HashMap<Candidate> ?

Comment: Surest way to find out is trying and benchmarking, right? This is not all that complicated to test, I'd say.

Comment: If you can arrange for a contiguous index key of each candidate (apparently you can), the fastest way is to have a single array of `Candidate`. If you have three arrays, the CPU caches won't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> both ArrayList and HashTable are supposed to be O(1) for accessing and
>   O(1) for adding a value at the end, but would they really be as
>   performant?

To access and insert arraylist and hashtable have same overhead. But the search in arraylist is `O(N)` while in a hashtable is `O(1)`.
So if you need to search for a candidate hashtable is the best choice

Answer (score 1):

The fastest would be a `int[]`, if you have dense identifiers.

In my observations, *any* collection using primitive values can be a performance bottleneck, because of boxing and unboxing and the associated *memory overhead*. If your tasks are numerics heavy, avoid this at all cost.

A simple way to get fast collections for primitive values is to use the [GNU Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) libraries.

Either way: **theoretical complexity** does not guarantee good performance in practise. In theory, QuickSort is worse than HeapSort. In practise, it is better, because it is more CPU friendly, and the worst case situations can be avoided in practise with a good pivot choosing strategy. And that is the same thing here with Java: in theory, the cost is `O(1)`. In practise, it may come at quite a large memory management overhead. A code that is based on using `int[]` may have some operations in `O(n)` (e.g. ArrayCopy), but these translate to high-performance machine code, and come at a really low *real* cost.

BUT: **do you really need these at all?**

```
class Candidate {
   int votes;
   JLabel label;
}

ArrayList<Candidate> candidates;
```

is maybe all you need!

Comment: I just noticed... OP has a JLabel per each candidate. Guess how large that array must be. 50, 100? It's a trivial problem and a clear case of premature optimization.

Comment: Well, that may be only the part of data that is currently displayed. But yeah, I don't think his data will be really large. But the trove collections are largely drop-ins for the native collections.

Comment: thanks, i'll dig into that ! @Marko Topolnik: i won't have a very large data, but i'm curently learning Java and, even if i could have achieved it by many ways, i'd rather learn the best practices and undertand what is implied by each solution.

Comment: @BenoitHnte As far as best practices are concerned, you don't worry about optimization and design for simple and obvious code. In this case, a `HashMap<X, Candidate>` would be the idiomatic approach (where X stands for the type of your key, typically String or Integer).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't think he's mapping to candiates, but he has a class Candidate that has some fields. But maybe only `int Votes;` and a `JLabel display;` - then no maps are needed at all.